# Get the most top liked post ordered by time in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('User')
    text = models.TextField(max_length=320)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Likes(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post')
    liker = models.ForeignKey('User')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('post', 'liker')
```

I want to Get newest posts which their likes are more than 70. how can I write that query set with django orm ?

Comment: Why not have a go with what you have learnt by reading the documentation?

Comment: @Sayse Before this idea I used an integer field in my Post model to keep likes count and I use filter `Post.objects.filter(like__gt=70).order_by('created_date').all()` but it doesn't unique over likes. I create another Class and I want to use that query in this way.

Answer (score 4):

You need to annotate a count of the number of likes then filter on that

```
Post.objects.annotate(num_likes=Count('likes')).filter(num_likes__gt=70).order_by('-created_date')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do QV like this example.

```
qv = Likes.objects.filter(liker__gt = 70).all()
out = Post.objects.filter(id__in=qv).order_by('-created_at')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it doesn't work, i think `liker__gt = 70` is incorrect because liker is a primary key of User Model.